# JmsTemplate.convertAndSend throws Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.InterruptedIOException

Tags: jms, mule, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I was getting below exception when I tried to send a message to `activemq` Queue in my mule component using spring jms.

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:102) 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68) 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81) 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1394) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1510) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:325) 
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:196) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:457) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:543) 
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:653)
```

Code :

Using spring jms to send a message to queue. getting exception in the below line.

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend( queueName, jmsEventWrapper.wrapEvent(event), setDelay );
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a Spring jms template issue, unrelated to Mule.